# How to move content from one Server/Environment to Other Server/Environment

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Suppose we have 3 environments for LR namely , Development, Staging and Production.

For a content driven application, assume we have created all contents etc. in dev. site. Now we have to move them to Staging for customer verification and followed by Production.

Yes we can very well do this using Lar file. But is there any alternative to that.

In IBM WebSphere portal, we have option called syndication on click of this option , it automatically move the contents and relevant artifacts quickly. Is there any equivalent in LR.Lar file is very manual process so i want to do automation.Any ideas please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please note that [Content Creation is Not a Development Activity!](https://www.liferay.com/web/26526/blog/-/blogs/content-creation-is-not-a-development-activity-). Liferay has staging (local or remote) that will help you get this done on sites that contain productive content. But you must understand that there's quite a difference between code that you deploy and database content (i.e. content in the sense of the word)

That being said, up until Liferay 6.2 that was only a single step (from the staging to the production system), while Liferay 7 is implementing a multiple step staging process.